# maven clean install with release plugin

Tags: build, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

How do we integrate release plugin with `clean install`. Currently we execute `clean install -Pprofile,autoInstallPackage` to build and deploy the package to the environment after changing the SNAPSHOT version to release version in pom.xml.

We wanted to enhance the release process which includes updating pom with release version -> deploy using install profile -> creating a new Development Version.

for which `clean install release:prepare -Dresume=false -DreleaseVersion=3.2 -Dtag=3.2 -DdevelopmentVersion=3.3` works as well without deployment to environment.

I have problem in executing

```
`clean install -Pprofile,autoInstallPackage release:prepare -Dresume=false -DreleaseVersion=3.2 -Dtag=3.2 -DdevelopmentVersion=3.3`
```

this deploys a SNAPSHOT version rather than release version which makes sense as I don't have a proper sequence.

However, Using the below command doesn't work either:

`clean \
release:prepare -Dresume=false -DreleaseVersion=3.2 -Dtag=3.2 \
install -Pprofile,autoInstallPackage \
release:prepare -DdevelopmentVersion=3.3`

this is trying to execute git tag twice and fails. Still deploys the 3.2-SNAPSHOT version.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try [preparationGoals](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/run-goals-before-commit.html) in the [Maven-Release-Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/index.html) section of your pom.xml?

> To run additional goals after release preparation but before committing, specify them using the preparationGoals property.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <preparationGoals>clean install</preparationGoals>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

These maven goals are executed after the release is prepared, but prior to the submission of the release into source control.

The maven release goals are executed in this order:

- release:prepare
- preparationGoals
- release:perform
- completionGoals

Also, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991640/maven-releaseprepare-not-deploying-the-projects-with-release-version/5472734#5472734) and see if it also relates to your question.